# How to import enum defined in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have the following module defined in Typescript

```
declare module MyTypes {

    export enum MyEnum {
        GOOD = 'Good',
        BAD = 'Bad',
        UNKNOWN = '-'
    }

   export interface MyType1 {
      myType1:string
   }

}

export default MyTypes;
```

In a separate file, I import it like so:

```
import MyTypes from '/my-types'
import MyType1 = MyTypes.MyType1
import MyEnum = MyTypes.MyEnum
```

When I refer in the code to `MyEnum.GOOD,` Chrome returns an exception on the console `MyTypes` is not defined. What is the appropriate way to import enums from modules in typescript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using declare, typescript does *not* create any javascript code, it only implies that it already exists. With interfaces it all should work well, because they are just stripped at runtime. An enum on the other hand has actual string values like "Good".

You can simply remove the declare keyword and it all should work.

```
module MyTypes {

    export enum MyEnum {
        GOOD = 'Good',
        BAD = 'Bad',
        UNKNOWN = '-'
    }

   export interface MyType1 {
      myType1:string
   }

}

export default MyTypes;
```

FYI your enum in javascript would look like this:

```
export var MyEnum;
(function (MyEnum) {
    MyEnum["GOOD"] = "Good";
    MyEnum["BAD"] = "Bad";
    MyEnum["UNKNOWN"] = "-";
})(MyEnum || (MyEnum = {}));
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a reference about this I could read for learning?

Comment: @Edmondo1984 you can read about declaration files in here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html thats the only place to use declare